# How do I set the system environment variables permanently and not just for the virtual environment the python script is running in?

Tags: python, environment-variables

here is the code I am running:
python script:

```py
text = 'set TEST=TEST_VALUE'
res = os.system(text)
print(text + " exit code %d" % res)
```

output:

`set TEST=TEST_VALUE exit code 0`

I've also tried the following as well:

res = subprocess.run([text,""], shell=True)

os.environ["TEST"] = "TEST_VALUE"

and these only change the virtual env vars not the systems.

**UPDATE: resolution**

```
text = 'SETX TEST "TEST_VALUE" -m'
res = os.system(text)
print("resuls: ", res)
```

this works when you set the -m flag for SETX and you run your script in admin mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the virtual env vars"?

Comment: You can't change the environment variables *outside of* the program you're running.

Comment: @9769953 when you run a python script you get a copy of the current system environment and you can make changes to the environment the script is running in which I am calling the virtual environment since its not the system environments. Not sure what else to call it.

Comment: It is true that Python has no native way to set the environment variables when an account is logged in. On Linux/Mac, it seems likely that https://askubuntu.com/q/981123/1706131 could be used. On Windows, the `setx.exe` executable can be used. `SETX /?` for more details.

Comment: I call it subshell, or subprocess, or childprocess.

Comment: @lit this worked!! Thank you!!! I spent almost 5 hours looking everywhere trying to get stuff to work lol.

Comment: Glad you have something that works. I don't know that os.system() is fully deprecated, but there are many encouragements to use the much more capable `import subprocess` module.

Comment: Okay I'll switch to that, thank you again !!!